# Criação de abas sem retângulos

Tags: html, css

Preciso de uma pequena ajuda.
Tenho estas abas que estão a funcionar, mas visualmente não gosto dos retângulos onde clico e queria mudar.

Original: http://jsfiddle.net/f6jk903s/

Quero retirar as abas:

[image: O que eu tenho]

E colocar algo deste gênero:

[image: O que eu quero]

Já tentei varias formas mas não consigo substituir as tais abas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso usando a propriedade `border-radius`. Como só é necessário as bordas em cima do elemento, você usa as propriedades específicas para cada lado (o `border-radius` é simplesmente uma versão encurtada das 4 para cada lado. Exemplo:

```css
.tab {
    width:70px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px #ccc solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab"></div>
<div class="tab"></div>
<div class="tab"></div>
```

Dei um update no seu código do JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6jk903s/1/. Repare que eu tirei umas coisas desnecessárias, como a borda à esquerda na `ul.tabs`.

Para saber mais sobre a propriedade: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: Correcto, desde de já muito obrigado. 
Mas é possível retirar esses botões para mudar de noticia e colocar como tenho na imagem 2?